# Nuxt.js with TypeScript: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Vue and Nuxt. Doing a tutorial with TypeScript currently. It throws me a bunch of errors of `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y'.` An example below;

```bash
ERROR in components/AboutMe.vue:56:27
TS2339: Property 'routes' does not exist on type '{ components: { CButton: any; }; props: { user: { type: ObjectConstructor; default: undefined; }; }; data(): { expand: boolean; showTitle: boolean; showReadMore: boolean; routes: string[]; compiledBio: string; }; beforeMount(): void; mounted(): void; }'.
    54 |   },
    55 |   mounted() {
  > 56 |     this.showTitle = this.routes.every((r) => this.$route.name !== r)
       |                           ^^^^^^
    57 |     if (this.$route.name === `users-userSlug`) {
    58 |       this.expand = true
    59 |       this.showReadMore = false
```

Others are `Property 'showTitle' does not exist`, `'expand'` and etc. Basically everything with `this.` throws errors.

This is the `<script` block of `AboutMe.vue` component.

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { CButton } from '@chakra-ui/vue'

export default {
  components: {
    CButton,
  },
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      expand: false,
      showTitle: false,
      showReadMore: true,
      routes: [`users-userSlug-posts`, `users-userSlug`],
      compiledBio: ``,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showTitle = this.routes.every((r) => this.$route.name !== r)
    if (this.$route.name === `users-userSlug`) {
      this.expand = true
      this.showReadMore = false
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong?

I am using nuxt.js (v2.14.6)

### Edit 1 for @BoussadjraBrahim

I added `Vue.extend({})` and now most errors go away. But some of them still exist.

```bash
ERROR in components/Description.vue:138:10
TS2339: Property 'showAboutUs' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<{ post: any; }>>'.
    136 |   },
    137 |   mounted() {
  > 138 |     this.showAboutUs = this.$route.name !== `users-userSlug-posts`
        |          ^^^^^^^^^^^
    139 |   },
    140 |   methods: {
    141 |     open() {

ERROR in components/Description.vue:142:12
TS2339: Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<{ post: any; }>>'.
    140 |   methods: {
    141 |     open() {
  > 142 |       this.isOpen = true
        |            ^^^^^^
    143 |     },
    144 |     close() {
    145 |       this.isOpen = false
```

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    const showAboutUs: Boolean = false
    const isOpen: Boolean = false

    return {
      showAboutUs,
      isOpen,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showAboutUs = this.$route.name !== `users-userSlug-posts`
  },
  methods: {
    open() {
      this.isOpen = true
    },
    close() {
      this.isOpen = false
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: That means that this doesn't have "routes". You're embedding routes into the return of the data method. You're going to have to add them as a property on the AboutMe.vue component if you want to access them as this.routes. Alternately, you could do this.data().routes

Comment: How do I add them as property?

Comment: It looks like you are using things on the Vue component type. You need to tell typescript that this object is a vue component. I don't know Vue, so I can't really help you with that.

Answer (score 9):

To get types inference you should create the component using `Vue.extend({})` :

```
<script lang="ts">
import { CButton } from '@chakra-ui/vue'

import  Vue from "vue"

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    CButton,
  },
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      expand: false,
      showTitle: false,
      showReadMore: true,
      routes: [`users-userSlug-posts`, `users-userSlug`],
      compiledBio: ``,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showTitle = this.routes.every((r) => this.$route.name !== r)
    if (this.$route.name === `users-userSlug`) {
      this.expand = true
      this.showReadMore = false
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

I recommend to type your data properties to enforce the component typing :

```
 data() {
    const routes:Array<string>: [`users-userSlug-posts`, `users-userSlug`];
  // do the same thing with the other properties
    return {
      expand: false,
      showTitle: false,
      showReadMore: true,
      routes,
      compiledBio: ``,
    }
  },
```

[image: Edit long-sun-7944y]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been search for this for hours. But how did you know that? 
Where is it specificated at documentation?

Comment: I found it https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage and here https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: @boussadjra-brahim  One question: should this be done on all components? I thought the settings in the vue-shim.d.ts file would do this.

Comment: @JG_GJ this should be done for all components

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Vue.extend({})`

Example:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { CButton } from '@chakra-ui/vue'
import  Vue from "vue"

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    CButton,
  },
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined,
    },
  },
...
</script>
```

Hopefully this helps you