# Property '$router' does not exist on type, nuxt and typescript?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I have recently integrated typescript into a nuxt project and am getting that $ router error, as well as the properties I have declared inside

`data(){ return {property1: ''} }`

Performing it as indicated in the documentation https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/es/cookbook/components I no longer receive these errors, but I have doubts about how to do so as not to have to add this part to each component

```
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue.extend({
       data(){
        return {
            property1: ''
        }
       }
    });
```

and have it only as
`export default { data(){return {property1: ''}}}`

I have made the configuration in `types/vue-shim.d.ts`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import { Route } from "vue-router";
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
// Expansion
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $router: VueRouter;
    $route: Route;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65221545/nuxt-js-with-typescript-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y maybe help you