# Nuxt 2 + Typescript: Property '...' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I added typescript to my existing nuxt@2.15.8 application following instructions from official docs ([typescript](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/), [Composition API](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/)) and from some other blogs when official docs resulted in the error.

I checked these questions, nothing helped:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555089/resolve-property-does-not-exist-on-type-vue-error), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65221545/nuxt-js-with-typescript-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y) (`Vue.extend()` didn't work either)

Neither of `$fetchState`/`fetchState` syntaxes work as well.

Here's the code of the component:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="exam"> <!-- Property 'exam' does not exist on type '{}'. -->
    <Spinner v-if="$fetchState.pending" /> <!-- Property '$fetchState' does not exist on type '{}'. -->
    <div v-else-if="fetchState.error">An error occurred</div> <!-- ...'fetchState' does not exist... -->
    <div v-else>
      {{ exam.results }} <!-- Property 'exam' does not exist on type '{}'. -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  ref,
  useContext,
  useFetch,
  useRoute,
  watch,
} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import Spinner from '~/components/global/spinner.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Spinner,
  },
  setup() {
    const ctx = useContext()

    const route = useRoute()
    const exam = ref({})

    const testId = computed(() => +route.query.test_id)

    const { fetch, fetchState } = useFetch(async () => {
      const { data } = await ctx.$api.get('/student/view-test', { params: { testId } })
      exam.value = data.data
    })

    watch(testId, () => {
      fetch()
    })

    return { exam, fetchState }
  },
})
</script>
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "~~/*": ["./*"],
      "@@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": ["@types/node", "@nuxt/types"]
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"],
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "target": 2
  }
}
```

Here's my `types/vue-shim.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 3080",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 3080",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".ts,.js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.33.1",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.2.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "3",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "nuxt": "2.15.8",
    "nuxt-trailingslash-module": "^1.1.0",
    "nuxt-webfontloader": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@vue/compiler-dom": "^3.2.40",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "prettier": "latest"
  }
}
```

Here's my `buildModules` in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxt/typescript-build', // I tried disabling this, no difference
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api',
    // '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module', // This instead of the above line doesn't help either
  ],
```

I honestly tried a lot of other small things that I don't remember, they got me closer but this error still shows up. Also I tried to reload VSCode's window and VSCode is updated to the latest version ;)

I feel like something is wrong with the `ref` object imported from `@nuxtjs/composition-api`, because when I hover over it, it just shows this:

[image: hover on ref]

And refs created in the setup function don't implicitly get the types from the values that were put into ref's argument like `const myRef = ref("text")` where `myRef` should be a ref of string but it's just `any`.

And when I hover on other things it's normal:
[image: Other imports]

When I start the project in development mode the terminal throws me an error/warning that says:

```
ERROR [Vue warn]: Property or method "exam" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is 
reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

But the server doesn't stop because of that. The component doesn't show the contents of `exam` obviously though.

Comment: Maybe you should try Nuxt 3 version because it has fantastic typescript and vue3 support out of the box. Even more, there is a supported version of Vitesse - started template by @antfu https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-nuxt3. I think it might be faster than configuring all these things.

And I found one more Nuxt official template for typescript with nuxt 2 version- https://github.com/nuxt-community/typescript-template